# MVC ASP.NET Url.Action in form action, passing it form data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
        <form action="@Url.Action("PokemonSteps", "PokemonView", new { id = Model.Id, steps = steps })">
            <input type="number" name="steps" min="1" max="@Model.userSteps">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

This form is a number box from 1 to the amount of steps the user has.
When they submit the number in the box, I want to pass it to `@Url.Action` as the `steps` in the `steps = steps` part.

How do I go about that (sorry for the really stupid question)

Comment: Not clear what your asking. You should not have `new { steps = steps }` - you have a form control named `steps` and the value of that control will be posted when you submit the form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="@Url.Action("PokemonSteps", "PokemonView")" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id">
   <input type="number" name="steps" min="1" max="@Model.userSteps">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please add Attribute **method="post"** and share your controller method signature also...

Comment: that was enough for me to understand what I was doing wrong, thank you
Also adding HttpPost to my controller method and it's perfect

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PokemonSteps", "PokemonView", FormMethod.Post)){    
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.userSteps)
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Hope this Helps!!