# $('#Form').submit vs $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to do a

```
1) $('#form').submit();
```

but this way

```
2) $.post('/controller/function',formData,function(result){
// I want here to do the same as $('#form').submit();
});
```

Explanation when i do 1) on the return it will fill all my inputs with the model related to the view that I return on the server side

```
return View(model);
```

Also if I return a not related view and model by specifying the view on the server side it will load the view with the model.

```
return View(view,model);
```

I like this behaviour but the bad side of it, it will always call the same function on the server side

What I want I want to be able to call different function on the server side and keeping the same behavior as the one happen when I call 1)

With 2) I can call the function I want but I don't know how to make the return acting the same as 1) (automatically fill my inputs or return redirect the good view with the model loaded (filled inputs with model data))

Server side (if it can help)

```
//Use when I perform some search on my page or few actions
//Called with 1) 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult defaultFunction(Model model)
{
 //Doing some code
 return View(model);
}
//Use on button click I want to switch page to perform some action
//Return the view with the model all ready for the action to be 
//perform by the user
//Called with 2) but not doing what I want
// If I move the code in the defaultFunction and called it with 1) it do 
//what I want : redirect the browser to the view with the model ... 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult redirectFuntion(Model model)
{
 //Doing some code
 return View("View",model);
}
```

Thank you 
And sorry English it not my first language.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing anything but it's all about which action you set in the FORM element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325846/mvc-asp-net-url-action-in-form-action-passing-it-form-data

Comment: @kblok Currently my form doesn't have and action only a id and method="post"

Comment: So that's the trick

Comment: @kblok not sure i am trying it and it  doesn't work It load the good page but all my model is in the "adress bar" like when you doing a get and my model is not loaded in the view (all the inputs are not filled)

Comment: @kblok well nvm it worked now i replace my return RedirectToAction by a return view on the server side and it work! Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @kblok

With his comments I did this for my solution :

```
$('#form').attr('action','/controller/function').submit();
// it doing the same as if i did $('form').submit(); but I can specified the
// called function on the server side.
```

and it work !